# No package 'gobject-introspection-1.0' found while deploying to Heroku

Tags: python, ubuntu, heroku

Attempted to deploy python web app to heroku but encountered the following errors:

```
remote:            running build_ext
remote:            Package gobject-introspection-1.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
remote:            Perhaps you should add the directory containing `gobject-introspection-1.0.pc'
remote:            to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
remote:            No package 'gobject-introspection-1.0' found
remote:            Command '('pkg-config', '--print-errors', '--exists', 'gobject-introspection-1.0 >= 1.46.0')' returned non-zero exit status 1.
remote:            
remote:            Try installing it with: 'sudo apt install libgirepository1.0-dev'
remote:            
remote:            ----------------------------------------
remote:        Command "/app/.heroku/python/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-l6sq2i_i/PyGObject/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-k7lo0r2b-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-l6sq2i_i/PyGObject/
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to ggoh-trailer.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/ggoh-trailer.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/ggoh-trailer.git'
```

OS = Ubuntu 18.04(Bionic)
Python 3.7.1

In requirements.txt:

pycairo==1.18.0
PyGObject==3.30.2

I've installed libgirepository1.0-dev as below;

```
$ whereis gobject-introspection-1.0
gobject-introspection-1: /usr/include/gobject-introspection-1.0 /usr/share/gobject-introspection-1.
```

But I still see the same error above. Are there any other applications that I need to install on Ubuntu to fulfill the dependency?

Comment: This has nothing to do with your local Ubuntu machine: the error is happening on Heroku. What are you using Cairo for?

Answer (score 0):

After manually editing requirement.txt files with content below;

```
Flask
gunicorn
```

Heroku was able to accept my git push. I've learned to only use the required dependencies in requirement.txt. Thanks Chris for point me to the right direction.