# No package found error while pushing to heroku a flask app

Tags: python, heroku, flask

I am trying to deploy a Flask app on Heroku which responds to JSON post requests after doing some data analysis on a big JSON dataset. I referred to this question: [No package 'gobject-introspection-1.0' found while deploying to Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53362778/no-package-gobject-introspection-1-0-found-while-deploying-to-heroku) but it's still not working.

`requirements.txt`:

```
flask
pandas
gunicorn
flask_cors
gdown
```

```
Package gobject-introspection-1.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
remote:            Perhaps you should add the directory containing `gobject-introspection-1.0.pc'
remote:            to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
remote:            No package 'gobject-introspection-1.0' found
remote:            Command '('pkg-config', '--print-errors', '--exists', 'gobject-introspection-1.0 >= 1.46.0')' returned non-zero exit status 1.
remote:            
remote:            Try installing it with: 'sudo apt install libgirepository1.0-dev'
remote:            
remote:            ----------------------------------------
remote:        Command "/app/.heroku/python/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-3ejh6vw4/PyGObject/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-lgaouqha-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-3ejh6vw4/PyGObject/
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to stormy-castle-60587.
```

Comment: You can try to reach your slug with `heroku run bash --app appname` and then try to install `libgirepository1.0-dev`. In case of failure, use `heroku-community/apt`, more info at: https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/heroku/heroku-buildpack-apt.

Comment: thanks it worked,I was successfully able to deploy my Flask app

Comment: Ok, I've converted my comment to an answer. Please accept and upvote it if you found that helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to reach your slug with `heroku run bash --app appname` and then try to install `libgirepository1.0-dev`. In case of failure, use `heroku-community/apt`, more info at [heroku-buildpack-apt](http://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/heroku/heroku-buildpack-apt)